# _tfopen_s can function when passed a constant string, but cannot when passed a variable

Tags: c++, memory

Hi when I am openning a file in UNICODE environment, it works well with:
  `_tfopen_s(fp,TEXT("C://puttty.exe"),TEXT("rb"));`
But in the following it doesn't work in a function:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

INT_PTR CALLBACK    MainDlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


struct  _PE_INFO
{
    TCHAR* szFileName;
};

class PEFile
{
public:
    _PE_INFO pe_info;

public:
    PEFile();
    virtual ~PEFile();

public:
    int ReadPEFile(_PE_INFO& pe);
    VOID PEFile::OpenFile(LPOPENFILENAME lpOpenFileName, HWND hWndDlg);
};

PEFile::PEFile()
{

}

PEFile::~PEFile()
{

}

int PEFile::ReadPEFile(_PE_INFO& pe)
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    errno_t t = _tfopen_s(&fp, pe.szFileName, TEXT("rb"));
    return t;
}

VOID PEFile::OpenFile(LPOPENFILENAME lpOpenFileName, HWND hWndDlg)
{
    TCHAR szPeFileExt[100] = TEXT("*.exe;*.dll;*.scr;*.drv;*.sys");
    TCHAR szFileName[256];
    memset(szFileName, 0, 256);
    memset(lpOpenFileName, 0, sizeof(*lpOpenFileName));
    lpOpenFileName->lStructSize = sizeof(*lpOpenFileName);
    lpOpenFileName->Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;
    lpOpenFileName->hwndOwner = hWndDlg;
    lpOpenFileName->lpstrFilter = szPeFileExt;
    lpOpenFileName->lpstrFile = szFileName;
    lpOpenFileName->nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;

    GetOpenFileName(lpOpenFileName);
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK MainDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PEFile test;
    OPENFILENAME stOpenFileName = { 0 };
    int t = -1;
    //int t = test.ReadPEFile(test.pe_info);
    switch (uMessage)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
        break;
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        test.OpenFile(&stOpenFileName,hDlg);
        test.pe_info.szFileName = stOpenFileName.lpstrFile;
        t = test.ReadPEFile(test.pe_info);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}



int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    //test.pe_info.szFileName = TEXT("C:\\putty.exe");
    DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, MainDlgProc);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And I followed the memory when debuging, I see the szFileName is changed in the process of _tfopen_s, and then shows that the file doesn't exist or system is busy.

I think maybe it's the problem from the class.. Thanks for help!

Comment: add the code calling your `ReadFile`: the problem is likely there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks guys. I amended the code to a compliable one.